# Comparing two definitions of determinant of coherent sheaves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, coherent-sheaves

Let $f:X \to S$ be a smooth, projective morphism of $k$-schemes for some field $k$. Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a coherent sheaf on $X$ flat over $S$. We know (by Proposition $2.1.10$ of Huybrechts-Lehn, Geometry of the moduli space of sheaves) that $\mathcal{F}$ has a finite locally free resolution, say $$0 \to \mathcal{E}_n \to ... \to \mathcal{E}_1 \to \mathcal{F} \to 0.$$ We can define determinant of $\mathcal{F}$ as $\otimes_{i=1}^n (\mbox{det}(\mathcal{E}_i))^{(-1)^i}$. There is another definition of determinant of $\mathcal{F}$ as the top exterior power (exterior product with itself takes rank $\mathcal{F}$ number of times, the definition of rank coming from the leading coefficient of the Hilbert polynomial of $\mathcal{F}$). Is there any relation between these two definitions? When are they the same?

Comment: The first definition gives you a line bundle (invertible sheaf). The second one does not, in general. They will agree for locally free sheaves, but I doubt that they will agree for any other sheaf.

Comment: And I vote to close because it is not a research question.

Comment: What is the role of $f$ and $S$ in the question?

Comment: @abx: If the coherent sheaf is not flat over $S$ then it is not necessary that $\mathcal{F}$ has a finite locally free resolution. That was the only role of $f$ and $S$.

Comment: If $D>0$ is an effective divisor, and $F:=O_X/O_X(-D)$, then the obvious resolution shows that $\det F=O_X(D)$. But $F$ has rank $0$, so the top exterior power gives you $O_X$.